# How to use map::end from map::find in C++

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator

I want to use the C++ map function, [map::find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/find/), to determine if a specific string is within a map. I know that find returns `map::end` but I am not sure on how to use it. So if the same string exists in both `names_` and `info_`, I want it to print that string to the screen.

In my header:

```
std::vector<std::string>names_;
std::map<std::string, unsigned int> info_;
```

In the .cpp (THIS CODE IS WRONG):

```
for(unsigned int i=0;i<names_.size();i++){
    std::map<std::string, unsigned int>::iterator it;
    it = info_.find(names_[i]);
    if info_.find(names_[i]) != info_.end()
        std::cout << names_[i] << std::endl; 
}
```

What I am doing wrong in the .cpp code snipet? I know it is something with iterators.

Comment: what's exactly wrong, aside of missing parentheses in `if` statement?

Comment: For boolean existence test it's simpler to use `map.count(item)` which will return 1 or 0 (or more with a multimap).

Comment: @Ben `.count()` is inefficient for testing existence in multimaps (O(n)).

Comment: @Chris: Where are the multimaps in this question?

Comment: @Elpezmuerto: Next time, tell us the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be:

```
for(unsigned int i=0;i<names_.size();i++){
    if (info_.find(names_[i]) != info_.end())
        std::cout << names_[i] << std::endl; 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Apart from anything else:

```
if info_.find(names_[i]) != info_.end()
```

should be:

```
if ( info_.find(names_[i]) != info_.end() )
```

In C++ (and C) conditions tested by ifs and whiles must be enclosed in parens.

Answer (score 1):

After the obvious fix of enclosing the if expression if brackets mentioned in the other answers, the code works.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::vector<std::string>names_;
  std::map<std::string, unsigned int> info_;
  names_.push_back("a");
  names_.push_back("b");
  names_.push_back("c");
  info_["a"] = 123;
  info_["c"] = 123;
  info_["d"] = 456;
  for(unsigned int i=0;i<names_.size();i++){
      std::map<std::string, unsigned int>::iterator it;
      if (info_.find(names_[i]) != info_.end())
          std::cout << names_[i] << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Output:

```
a
c
```

Isn't that what you asked for?